# Should the file ".XE.created" be there?

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle21c

the docker container "container-registry.oracle.com/database/express:21.3.0-xe" didn't run the post-setup scripts. The post-startup scripts works fine.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    image: container-registry.oracle.com/database/express:21.3.0-xe
    container_name: db
    ports:
      - "1521:1521"
      - "5500:5500"
    environment:
      - ORACLE_PWD=oracle
    volumes:
      - ./oracle/script:/opt/oracle/scripts/setup
```

The reason could be, that the file `.XE.created` is already created

```
sh-4.2$ ls -la /opt/oracle/oradata
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 1 oracle oinstall 4096 Mar 30 10:47 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 oracle oinstall 4096 Mar 30 10:38 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle oinstall    0 Mar 30 10:47 .XE.created
drwxr-x--- 1 oracle oinstall 4096 Mar 30 10:47 XE
drwxr-xr-x 1 oracle oinstall 4096 Mar 30 10:47 dbconfig
```

This in combination with https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/8acbbd735e9a7a93a6bec66c1d10b564a25634b4/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/dockerfiles/21.3.0/runOracle.sh#L236 leads to the behaviour that post-setup is never called.

Is there a way to fix this?